# How can I search a regex using a list of strings?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of Amazon facilities:

`locs = [LGB6, OAK5]`

Say I have a string as such:

`amz_string = 'LGB6 is in Riverside, CA'`

Here's what I tried doing:

```
r = re.compile(amz_string)
filter(r.search. locs)
```

My output becomes `[]`

Comment: Probably, [`[x for x in amz_string.split() if any(item in x for item in locs)]`](https://ideone.com/JZNgVG) will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.join`:

```
import re
locs = ['LGB6', 'OAK5']
amz_string = 'LGB6 is in Riverside, CA'
new_results = re.findall('|'.join(locs), amz_string)
```

Output:

```
['LGB6']
```